What are all the triggers or 'signals' in Signal 100?
I saw the live action film, and found out that it was based on a manga, so I figured I would ask here.
Does anyone have a complete list of all the triggers? I know crying, acting violent, reading comics, using phones, drinking from bottles, staring too long at someone, leaving school grounds, beer showers, non authorized clothing, having 7 people pointing at you all at once, touching sexually stimulated parts, and staying at school until dawn are all triggers for suicide, at least in the film, maybe not on the manga.
Please share the rest if they are known.

Also posted on Movies.SE: https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/123757/15983

Having read the series and editing the community wiki I think this is as complete of a list as there is for the manga, although signals 34-50 were never revealed and signals 86-88 despite being shown were too difficult to make out and my Japanese isn't good enough to inference what they could be

In the original manga:



No.
Trigger
Chapter




001
Violence towards other people
1


002
Telling non-classmate about the incident
1


003
Nose picking
3


004
Kicking a ball with right leg
3


005
Sitting in the school hallway
3


006
Drinking coffee
3


007
Yawning in front of a teacher
3


008
Touching a boner
3


009
Laughing out loud
3


010
Tripping and falling
3


011
Losing in a rock-paper-scissor game
3


012
Throwing non-trash into trash bin
3


013
Leaving the school area
4


014
Hanging down with both hands
9


015
Taking off indoor slippers with a hand
9


016
Writing own name
9


017
Plugging and unplugging power plug
9


018
Drinking water from plastic bottle
6


019
Combing up one's hand through one's hair
9


020
Staring silently at someone for more than 15 seconds
9


021
Skipping 1 stair step while climbing
9


022
Drawing lottery
9


023
More than 25 classmates pointing at you at the same time
6


024
Walking while holding hands for more than 5 seconds
9


025
Taking a picture with a mobile phone
9


026
Eating rice
9


027
Eating dish on plates
9


028
Dropping eating utensils
9


029
Vomiting on ground
9


030
Wearing earphones
9


031
Knocking on doors more than 3 times
9


032
Wetting oneself
2


033
Touching money with hands
9


034-050
(Never revealed)
N/A


051
Kneeling on the ground in underwear only
9


052
Inserting pachinko ball into nose
13


053
Inserting adult toy into mouth
12


054
Jumping while one's foot is pierced with thumb tack
13


055
Saying "I am a fool (aho)" 100 times
13


056
Dropping hammer to one's left foot
13


057
Eating cheese with already passing the best-for date
13


058
Making a burn mark on the right hand
13


059
Pouring cooking oil on head
12


060
Sticking cellophane tape on the face and pulling it
13


061
Putting chalk powder on face
11


062
Puttting right middle finger in between door
13


063
Cutting hair with scissors
10


064
Piercing left thigh with a pen
11


065
Pulling out 1 lower tooth
13


066
Pouring disinfectant alcohol on eye
13


067
Writing "Fool (aho)" on forehead
13


068
Smashing lightbulb with hand
13


069
Crushing cockroach with hand
13


070
Biting aluminum foil with left teeth
13


071
Start walking with your left leg
23


072
Touch someone else's hand
23


073
Smile
23


074
Get mad
24


075
Stand up
24


076
Run
24


077
Point at someone
24


078
Fumble your words
24


079
Touch your face
24


080
Doubt another person
24


081
Put your palms together
24


082
Cry
24


083
Say somebody's name
25


084
Go to the toilet
25


085
Talk to someone you've never talked to before
25


086
Sigh? (too blurry)
27


087
Jump... (rest is cut off)
27


088
Eye... (rest is cut off)
27


092
Sneeze
25


093
Look behind you
25


094
Wipe away sweat
25


095
Ask a question
24


096
Start walking with your right leg
24


097
Sniffle
24


098
Step backwards
24


099
Close one eye
24


100
Bask in sunlight
24



Signals 34-50 are never revealed

 Signals 71-100 only take effect starting from 4AM for specific people and spread to affect everyone at 5AM

